# Euclidean Algorithm for GCD of polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I am struggling to use the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials.

Given something like $$GCD(x^5+1, x^3+1)$$

I can easily use it as follows:

$$x^5+1 = x^2(x^3+1) -x^2 +1 \\
x^3+1 = -x(-x^2+1) + x +1 \\
-x^2+1 = (x+1)(-x+1)$$

GCD = x+1

But for something like $$GCD(2x^2+6x+3, 2x+1)$$

I cannot figure out how to do it using the same method. I start like this:

$$2x^2+6x+3 = x(2x+1) + 5x+3\\
2x+1 = \frac{2}{5}(5x+3) - \frac{1}{5}\\$$

and I am not sure how to continue. Any help would be appreciated, sorry for my poor attempt at using LaTeX.

Comment: If I've reverse engineered your method... you've shown $\gcd(2x^2 + 6x + 3,2x+1) = \gcd(5x+3, -1/5)$. Isn't the next step to find the remainder when $2x+1$ is divided by $-1/5$? If it helps, since $-5$ is presumably invertible, that means you can multiply or divide one of the arguments by it whenever you like.

Comment: For this case, you will either have $2x+1$ divides $2x^2+6x+3$ or they are coprime. So you just need to check the divisability of $2x^2+6x+3$.

Comment: Also, the remainder after the division should always have degree less than the divisor, so you can see your division is not done at the first step.

Comment: When you do GCD with integers, you can stop when you get remainder $1$, because everything is divisible by $1$. When you do it with polynomials with rational (or real or complex or..) coefficients, you can stop whenever you reach a constant, because every polynomial is divisible by all non-zero constants.

Comment: You should actually do the division $2x^2+6x+3 = (x+\frac52)(2x+1) + \frac12$

Comment: So (following Hurkyl's suggestion) the next step shows that $2x+1$ is divisible by $1/5$, and the algorithm terminates with answer $1/5$. All the non-zero constants are associates in the polynomial ring, so any one of them works just as well as GCD. The choice GCD=1 is commonly made, because then (as in the case of integers) this indicates that there are no (interesting) common divisors.

Comment: @Easy It is not necessary that one uses the *least* remainder at each step.

Comment: I still don't really understand. If I continued then I would think to do: (5x+3) = -1/5(-25x-15) + 0. And so GCD = 1? I don't understand why I would show that 2x+1 is divisible by 1/5 instead?

Comment: @user: If $a | b$, then $\gcd(a,b) = a$. If you take a remainder, then $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(0,a) = a$. Either way you get the same result. Taking remainders until you get zero requires less thought; but if you see a way to identify the answer early, it's fine to do so.

Answer (score 5):

As $(a,b)=(a+n\cdot b,b),$ where $n$ is any integer

$$(2x^2+6x+3,2x+1=((2x+1)x+5x+3,2x+1)=(5x+3,2x+1)$$

Now, $2(5x+3)-5(2x+1)=1\implies(5x+3,2x+1)=1$

Answer (score 3):

You can observe that if you divide any polynomial then degree of remainder is less than that of divisor . If you divide $2x^2+6x+3$ by 2x+1 the remainder is 13/2 and they also don't have any common constants . So the GCD will be 1.

Answer (score 3):

A "complete" explanation in response to your question requires using words like
content and primitive part.  The wikipedia article on polynomial
greatest common divisor would help.  If you conclude using your divisions that the final non-zero remainder is $1/5$, over the field of rationals, then the primitive part of this is $1$, which you want.

Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming Vol. 2* section 6.2 is still a good
discussion.  You might also learn that the notion of division with remainder is generally extended, for purposes of polynomial GCD, to pseudo-division.
This removes the need for doing calculations with rational numbers.
Then for polynomials $f,g$:

$$\gcd(f,g)=\gcd(\text{content}(f),\text{content}(g))\cdot\gcd(\text{primpart}(f),\text{primpart}(g)).$$

Given your particular question, assuming that you want your GCD to correspond to the usual notion, namely as a **polynomial in $x$ with integer coefficients**, you would return the primitive part of $1/5$, (indeed the primitive part of any
constant), namely $1$.